# Temporary value dropped while borrowed - Rust

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker

I'm trying to iterate through a String via bytes iterator. My intent is to convert each byte into a single-letter `&str` which gets pattern matched. Based on the match arm, it will attempt to add the value to a Vector. However, I've been getting an error which is preventing the program to compile. The error message is this:

```
Line 15, Char 22: temporary value dropped while borrowed (solution.rs)
   |
15 |             let b = &[byte];
   |                      ^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
20 |                     stack.push(c);
   |                     ------------- borrow later used here
...
39 |         }
   |         - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0716`.
error: could not compile `prog` due to previous error
```

For reference, this is the underlying piece of code:

```rust
let mut stack: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();

for byte in s.bytes() {
    let b = &[byte];
    let c = str::from_utf8(b).unwrap();
            
    match c {
        "a" | "b" => {
            stack.push(c);
        },
        _ => println!("not a or b"),
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know you can match directly against `u8`?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't! My main concern was to understand the underlying reason for this particular issue but I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you create a temporary array, `[byte]`, and try to push a borrow of it into the `Vec`. But the array lives only to the end of the scope - and the `Vec` lives longer!

The usual solution will be to heap-allocate the `&str`: `stack.push(c.to_owned())`. But because the memory layout of one-element array matches that of the element, you can go without allocating. First, you need to get a reference to byte with the same lifetime as the original `&str` instead of a by-value byte. This can be done by iterating over `s.as_bytes()` (that returns `&[u8]`) instead of over `s.bytes()` (that returns `impl Iterator<Item = u8>`).

Second, you need to convert this byte into an array with the same lifetime. There is a function in the standard library to do that: [`std::array::from_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/array/fn.from_ref.html).

So:

```rust
let mut stack: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();

for byte in s.as_bytes() {
    let b = std::array::from_ref(byte);
    let c = str::from_utf8(b).unwrap();

    match c {
        "a" | "b" => {
            stack.push(c);
        }
        _ => println!("not a or b"),
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough rep yet to upvote but marking this as an accepted answer. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: So to be clear for myself, both `b` and `c` inherit the lifetime of `s` with this code?  That's kind of a neat trick, extending something's life outside of the scope that it's declared inside without using an `Rc`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yes, and `byte` too. We are not extending lifetimes here - this is impossible, rather, we use the fact that the memory layout is the same to retrieve parts of `s` (which of course has the same lifetime), but with a new type.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman - Fair that "extending" is the wrong word.  I guess I'm used to using the rule of thumb that you can't add references to something that's inside a more strict scope block (doesn't live long enough), and that's _similar to_ what's happening here.  But I _do_ understand that they're getting their lifetimes from `s` which is non-intuitive, that's all.  I'm glad for it, just not my first thought.  I need to remember that if a function's input is a reference, and it outputs a reference, the lifetime is the same as the original, no matter what scope it's assigned to.